# s2geometry installation failing on Colab

Tags: python, package, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install s2geometry on Colab.
!pip install s2geometry

I am getting the following error. Can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSM0N.png)

I also tried building and installing after cloning from github. Still the same error.

Comment: [Post your code/data/errors as text, not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker, use this or try something like this.

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
```